# Interface of QGIS plugin created by QtCreator

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

The image below is the interface of the plugin which I created using Qt Creator.
[image]

However, when I loaded this plugin in QGIS3 (version: 3.6.1). The interface of the plugin does not appear completely. (Only some part of the text appeared.)
[image]

The same problem also occurs when I installed plugins from repositories.
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just had a similar problem, a solution might be to add a layout and add the labels, lineedit and comboxes in to it, also make sure that they are large enough (that the minimum width is large enough etc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem of the layout is solved. However, another problem happened. After I add a layout to the interface, the button of "OK" and "cancel" suddenly don't work. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm, that does not seem to be related, did you alter anything else?

Comment: No... I didn't change anything else. Let me try to fix this problem.....